# It is possible te get this view in webgl?

Tags: 3d, drawing, 2d, webgl

It is possible to get view as on screenshoot? It should generate 3d obiect from 2d drawn shape.
Could You tell me what liblaries could help me to get this funcionality?
Thanks a lot!

Screen: http://i.imgur.com/l7vQvUf.png

Comment: Yes, try http://threejs.org/editor/ or three.js engine. How does 2d drawn shape look like?

Comment: It look like like shape drawn on the left side of the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

You can get [three.js](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) and [extrude a geometry/shape](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) pretty much easily [and get it revolve around itself](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes).

If you need a gap in between like the picture, you can extrude your shape, clone it and make it revolve around the center of the scene. That can be easily achievable with a bit of understanding of trigonometry and how 3D spaces works.